# Using firebase in vuejs2 app via vue-cli(webpack)

Tags: firebase, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to using vue-cli **a webpack template**
I want to use firebase as my database for the vueapp
i have done this to import Firebase into my app

**main.js**

```
//imported rest all required packages just dint mention here
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

let config = {
apiKey: " - XXXXXXXXCXCC",
authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX",
databaseURL: "XXXXXCCCX",
storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
store,
render: h => h(App)
})
```

Now in my signup.vue file i have to import the following again

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
```

In order to use the following in my methods

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(uEmail, uPassword).catch(function(error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                // ...
            });
```

My question is do i have to import

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
```

everywhere (i.e in alll vue components script tags to use firebase related methods like

```
firebase.auth()
firebase.database()
firebase.storage()
```

**or can i import it at one central place and use `firebase.method() in any vue component file when needed`**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could attach the `firebase` to the `Vue.prototype`:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

let config = {
  //
}

Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config)

new Vue({
  //
})
```

Then, use it to the components like this:

```js
this.$firebase.database()
```

Comment: Thank you.... it worked... i used this method but forgot to access $firebase by putting "this" before it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import it just once, you can simply do in your `main.js`:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

window.firebase = firebase
```

`window` object is global for webpage and it's normal practice to use it this way.